# Individual + plural or individual + singular?

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence like:

> Morphological and statistical features of individual heartbeats are
>   used to...

I'm not sure whether it's correct or I should use `individual heartbeat`.

I googled it and it seems `individual` comes with both singular and plural nouns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Individual is indeed a noun and an adjective. When used as a **noun**, it refers to *a person*, or someone. For example:

> That individual over there is a nasty piece of work.

To give a couple of examples of the use of the **adjective**, using *heartbeat* in its singular and plural:

#### Singular

> You can feel each *individual heartbeat* when you take someone's pulse.

Or

> When I put my hand to your chest I can feel every *individual heartbeat*

**Note**: when singular, individual would be preceded by *each*, *every*, *one*, *an*, or *the*.

#### Plural

> If you add up all of the *individual heartbeats*, and divide them by the
> time you felt them in, that will give you the person's heart rate.

#### Summary

So, in short, use *individual heartbeat* if you are talking about one particular heartbeat, or *individual heartbeats* when referring to the separate heartbeats as an *ensemble*.

In the example that you provide,

> Morphological and statistical features of individual heartbeats are
> used to...

you are referring to the features of a **collection** (plural) of heartbeats (even though, you are considering each and every individual heartbeat), and so you are correct in using *individual heartbeats*